# csv writer gives additiona; "", using quotechar gives additional ' at the beginning of the line

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file, which has 100 rows, I want to create a new csv file with first 10 rows.

```
with open(output_file_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outputfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outputfile, quotechar="'")
    for row in islice(reader, 10):
        writer.writerow(row)
```

for some rows, this gives,

```
'entry_1 entry_2 ... entry_n'
```

if I use,

```
writer = csv.writer(outputfile)
```

then, i get,

```
""entry_1" "entrt_2" ... "entry_n""
```

when I use,

```
writer = csv.writer(outputfile, doublequote=False, escapechar='\\')
```

I get,

```
entry_1 entry_2 \"entry_3\" \"entry_4\" ... entry_n
```

how do I get,

```
entry_1  entry_2  entry_3 ... entry_n
```

???
where some of the entries have "" around them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just after posting the question, I was able to solve this,
I had to specify a delimiter in my reader.

```
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ' ')
```

and then use,

```
writer = csv.writer(outputfile, quotechar="'")
```

this gives the desired,

```
entry_1 entry_2 entry_3 ... entry_n
```

without any additional "".